# MYSQL - how to update a field for all items resulting from group by select statement

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a select like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 
FROM table WHERE field1= 5  AND field_flag =1 
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3 limit 1000;
```

I want to update field_flag for the resulting rows. How can I do that in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to update table where field1, field2, and field3 are in the set returned by your select statement ?

eg.

```
update table, 
     ( select field1, field2, field3 
       FROM table WHERE field1= 5  AND field_flag =1 
       GROUP BY field1, field2, field3 limit 1000 ) temp
set table.field_flag = 99 
where table.field1=temp.field1 and table.field2=temp.field2 and table.field3 = temp.field3
```

Note that the update might update many more than 1000 rows.

A temporary table could be used too:

```
create temporary table temptab as
select field1, field2, field3 
FROM table WHERE field1= 5  AND field_flag =1 
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3 limit 1000 

 update table, 
        temptab temp
 set table.field_flag = 99 
 where table.field1=temp.field1 and table.field2=temp.field2 and table.field3 = temp.field3
```

This has the advantage that temptab can be used later, and also that indexes can be added to speed up the update:

```
create index on temptab (field1, field2, field3);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. Is it possible to also return the select result so I wont have to query twice? once for the select and once for the flag update.

Comment: You could perform your select into a temporary table and use that.

create temporary table temptab as select field1, field2, ...
update table, temptab set table.field = 99 where table.field1 = temptab.field1 and ...

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
UPDATE table SET field_flag = <newvalue>
WHERE  idfield IN (
    SELECT idfield
    FROM table
    WHERE <conditions>
)
```

Comment: Thanks. But there is no single idfield.